# Hide / Unhide View in self sizing UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, uitableview, cocoa-touch, autolayout, ios-autolayout

I have a self sizing tableview cell which contains 3 cells as shown below

|----------------------------------|

Button1 ________ Label

(Hidden View)

|----------------------------------|

Button2 ________ Label

|----------------------------------|

Button3 ________ Label

|----------------------------------|

When I tap on Button 1, Cell 1 should expand and Hidden View should be visible and Cell 1 should expand based on hidden view height. Also when Hidden view is hidden, Cell 1 should shrink accordingly. How to achieve this.

Note: All 3 cell button state should change when Hidden view is hidden or shown.
Any good solution to achieve this?

Comment: Show some code for show/hide view? Also, do you use constraint for that?

Comment: @Tj3n I use autolayout constraint and I made my tableview cell self sizing as per apple guidelines and self sizing is working fine. Just want to show oe hide the view withanimation

Comment: try calling `tableview.beginUpdate` and `endUpdate`, it will recalculate height with animation

Answer (score 0):

Define one variable e.g. var isButtonOneTapped = Bool()

when you tap on that button set it true. i.e. isButtonOneTapped = true.
and reload table.

and set your tableview's delegates method according to that variable.

for exa: in heightForRow method

{
    if(isButtonOnetapped)

{

```
   return someValue

}
```

else

```
{

return otherValue

   }
```

}

Comment: I am not hardcoding tableview height. I use self sizing tableview whose height will be decided based on the contents intrinsic size

Comment: yes but you can calculate your tableview height in that condition.